# How to submit form to array and clear inputs in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue form inside a dialog. Where the user can select a date and multplie starting times and ending times. So far I can save one object consisting of one date and multiple times. But when I want to add another object it takes the new date but changes the time values for every object.

for example if I add first an object with 05.09.2021 start:15:00 end: 16:00 and then add another object with date: 06.09.2021 start: 16:00 end: 17:00. The start and end is changed to the latest value of all objects, but I want each of them to be individually. I tried submitting a form, but sadly I could not make it work because it is reloading the page which I do not want, if i use .prevent on submit my error with time changing for every object still consists. Could someone take a look at my code and point me my mistake out`?

HTML:

```
        <v-row>

          <v-col cols="12" sm="12">

                   <v-menu
                    ref="menu3"
                    v-model="menu3"
                    :close-on-content-click="false"
                    :return-value.sync="dates"
                    transition="scale-transition"
                    offset-y
                    min-width="auto"
              >
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" >
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="dates"
                  label="Picker in menu"
                  prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                  readonly
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on"
                ></v-text-field>
              </template>
              <v-date-picker
                v-model="dates"
                no-title
                scrollable
              >
                <v-spacer/>
                <v-btn
                  text
                  color="primary"
                  @click="menu3 = false"
                >
                  Cancel
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  text
                  color="primary"
                  @click="$refs.menu3.save(dates) "
                  v-on:click=" menu3 = false"
                >
                  OK
                </v-btn>
              </v-date-picker>
            </v-menu>
            <v-btn v-on:click="addTimeFields()">Add Time</v-btn>
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
        <v-row v-for="(find, index) in selectedTime" >
          <v-col
            cols="6"
            sm="6">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="find.startTime"
              label="Starttime"
              type="time"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col
            cols="6"
            sm="6">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="find.endTime"
              label="Untiltime"
              type="time"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        </form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
import MeetingsTableComponent from "@/components/MeetingsTableComponent";
import DatePickerComponent from "@/components/DatePickerComponent";

export default {
  name: "NextMeetingCardComponent",

  data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],
    dates: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
    datesFinal: [],
    dialog: false,
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false,
    menu3: false
  }),

  methods:{

    addTimeFields(){

      this.selectedTime.push({
        startTime:"",
        endTime: "",
      })
    },

    saveDateAndTIme(e){
      this.datesFinal.push({
        date: this.dates,
        times : [this.selectedTime]
        }

      )
      this.$refs.form.submit()
    },

    clearArrays(){
      while (this.selectedTime.length){
        this.selectedTime.pop()
      }
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

I tried clearing the selectedTimes array which is pushed to datesFinal after pushing it but then every value is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's an error in `saveDateAndTIme()`: `times` contains a nested array of the `this.selectedTime` array, but that should be unnested (i.e., set `times` to `this.selectedTime` itself).

After pushing `this.selectedTime` into `datesFinal`, you could clear the form by setting `this.selectedTime` to an empty array.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    saveDateAndTIme(e) {
      this.datesFinal.push({
        date: this.dates,
        times: this.selectedTime, 
      })
      this.selectedTime = [] 
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-form-data-after-submission-in-vuetify-n8009?file=/src/components/NextMeetingCardComponent.vue:2315-2380)